# React Native equivalent of React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When looking at React, specifically [React (Virtual) DOM terminology](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements) I am wondering whether there is an equivalent for React Native, or rather, how this can be modified for use with Native?

I am wanting to compose a view, it consists of a `<Text>` `<TouchableHighlight>` `<TouchableHighlight>` . The two `<TouchableHighlight>`elements will increment and decrement a counter (the `<Text>` label).

Is there a way I can perhaps pass these are parameters into a function similar to `React.createElement` that will return a view with these elements in?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

createElement is also available on React Native. So you can do:

`var textElem = React.createElement(Text, [], ['Hello world']);`

You must supply a ReactClass as first parameter, strings are not allowed as the first parameter in React Native since those are meant to be used for html tags in regular React.

Comment: For a `<TouchableHighlight>` I'm presuming you can pass a function in, similar to `onPress={this.doFunction.bind(this}` also the same for a `style={styles.button}`?

Comment: the second parameter is a list of props to be passed to the Component, so yes, you can pass those

Comment: I am trying to do `React.createElement(Text, {fontSize: 20}, 'hello world')` However it seems like the style is completely getting ignored. This seems to work in View but not in Text. Any idea why?

Comment: The second parameter is an object specifying the props. Can you try this? : `React.createElement(Text, {style: {fontSize: 20}}, 'hello world')`